# Server htaccess: rewrite URL with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^search?q=$   index.php?browse=1&q=$1  [L]
```

how can i send requests from /search?q=apple to /index.php?q=apple&browse=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search$    index.php?browse=1  [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you need to test the presence of `q=`, you can add before `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)q=.+(?:&|$) [NC]
```

Otherwise, it is automatically copied with `[QSA]`.
Because the query string is not part of the `RewriteRule` test.